# Use class variable inside a method of this class

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to update the value of a class variable when someone deposits money in my bank.

**My code**

```
class Bank_account():
    
    bank_balance = 0
    
    def __init__(self, name_holder, id, balance):
        self.name = name_holder
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
        bank_balance += balance
        
    def cash_in(self, cash):
        self.balance += cash
        bank_balance += cash
        
    def with_draw(self, draw):
        if self.balance < draw or bank_balance < draw:
            print('Error')
        else:
            print('Here your money!')

John = Bank_account('John', 123456, 2.10**6)
Smith = Bank_account('Smith', 111111, 3.10**6)
Michael = Bank_account('Michael', 123123, 4.10**6)

Bank_account.bank_balance
```

**My result**

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-0a83e2bc19e8> in <module>
     19             print('Here your money!')
     20 
---> 21 Quang = Bank_account('Quang', 123456, 2.10**6)
     22 Kien = Bank_account('Kien', 111111, 3.10**6)
     23 Trung = Bank_account('Trung', 123123, 4.10**6)

<ipython-input-30-0a83e2bc19e8> in __init__(self, name_holder, id, balance)
      7         self.id = id
      8         self.balance = balance
----> 9         bank_balance += balance
     10 
     11     def cash_in(self, cash):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bank_balance' referenced before assignment
```

Could anyone tell me how to use class variables and explain my error?

Comment: Just use ‘Bank_account.bank_balance += balance’ since ‘bank_balance’ is part of your class.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I just forgot that

Comment: The class level variable needs to be initialized, that happens when class is imported or the variable is used with class namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to, try the following:

(Notice I have added: `Bank_account.bank_balance` because that initializes the class variable as well. Verify that the output produced is what you want)

```py
class Bank_account:
    
    bank_balance = 0
    
    def __init__(self, name_holder, id, balance):
        self.name = name_holder
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
        Bank_account.bank_balance += balance   # change is here
        
    def cash_in(self, cash):
        self.balance += cash
        bank_balance += cash
        
    def with_draw(self, draw):
        if self.balance < draw or bank_balance < draw:
            print('Error')
        else:
            print('Here your money!')


John = Bank_account('John', 123456, 2.10**6)
Smith = Bank_account('Smith', 111111, 3.10**6)
Michael = Bank_account('Michael', 123123, 4.10**6)

print(Bank_account.bank_balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Bank_account():
    def __init__(self, name_holder, id, balance,bank_balance=0):
        self.name = name_holder
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
        self.bank_balance = balance
        
    def cash_in(self, cash):
        self.balance += cash
        self.bank_balance += cash
        
    def with_draw(self, draw):
        if self.balance < draw or bank_balance < draw:
            print('Error')
        else:
            print('Here your money!')

John = Bank_account('John', 123456, 2.10**6)
Smith = Bank_account('Smith', 111111, 3.10**6)
Michael = Bank_account('Michael', 123123, 4.10**6)

print(John.bank_balance)
```

I think this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: No, this makes `bank_balance` an instance variable and not a class variable. It should be `Bank_account.bank_balance += balance`.

Answer (score 0):

class Bank_account():

```
bank_balance = 0

def __init__(self, name_holder, id, balance):
    self.name = name_holder
    self.id = id
    self.balance = balance
    self.bank_balance += balance
    
def cash_in(self, cash):
    self.balance += cash
    bank_balance += cash
    
def with_draw(self, draw):
    if self.balance < draw or bank_balance < draw:
        print('Error')
    else:
        print('Here your money!')
```

John = Bank_account('John', 123456, 2.1-**6)

Smith = Bank_account('Smith', 111111, 3.10**6)

Michael = Bank_account('Michael', 123123, 4.10**6)

print(John.bank_balance)

Answer (score 0):

Since code inside a class, but outside of methods/functions is not executed, the variable is not declared in the momory. So, the solution would be to declare it in the *init* method in the following way:

```
class Bank_account():


    def __init__(self, name_holder, id, balance):
        # This has been changed 
        bank_balance = 0
        self.name = name_holder
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
        bank_balance += balance
        
    def cash_in(self, cash):
        self.balance += cash
        bank_balance += cash
        
    def with_draw(self, draw):
        if self.balance < draw or bank_balance < draw:
            print('Error')
        else:
            print('Here your money!')

John = Bank_account('John', 123456, 2.10**6)
Smith = Bank_account('Smith', 111111, 3.10**6)
Michael = Bank_account('Michael', 123123, 4.10**6)

Bank_account.bank_balance
```

Or if you want to access the bank balance detached from each bank_account object, just add a line saying `global bank_balance` in the following manner:

```
class Bank_account():


    def __init__(self, name_holder, id, balance):
        # This has been changed
        global bank_balance
        bank_balance = 0
        self.name = name_holder
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance
        bank_balance += balance
        
    def cash_in(self, cash):
        self.balance += cash
        bank_balance += cash
        
    def with_draw(self, draw):
        if self.balance < draw or bank_balance < draw:
            print('Error')
        else:
            print('Here your money!')

John = Bank_account('John', 123456, 2.10**6)
Smith = Bank_account('Smith', 111111, 3.10**6)
Michael = Bank_account('Michael', 123123, 4.10**6)

Bank_account.bank_balance
```

But I strongly recommend to add `self` before the `bank_balance` variable